# No service-worker.js in production build after deployment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest

My Progressive Web App (PWA) has `manifest.json` and `service-worker.js` in my production build when I am running it on a localhost (`serve -s dist`). Web app is installable. Everything is OK. I am using a Webpack with the Workbox plugin.

When I deploy to Vercel, there is only manifest file and no `service-worker.js` file.
How could it be?

Web-app: https://pricesapp.vercel.app

GitHub repo: https://github.com/eXebyss/pricesapp
[production build on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgVNx.png)

[production build on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8bpk.png)

[production build on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsMk6.png)

[production build on Vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB15X.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Well. Yes. But as far as I remember (some time has passed) I have used Workbox plugin for Webpack. Check the link to my repo on GitHub (https://github.com/eXebyss/pricesapp) . 
webpack.config.js / serviceWorkerRegistration.js and index.tsx